# sql inject magento keyword

Tags: php, mysql, magento, sql-injection

I have this kind of query strings on my magento search.

```
psak%' AND 8676=(SELECT UPPER(XMLType(CHR(60)||CHR(58)||CHR(113)||CHR(114)||CHR(114)||CHR(119)||CHR(113)||(SELECT (CASE WHEN (86
```

The weird thing is it has several results displayed and it is used around 30 times.
Looks like sql injection.
What is the behind this?
And how can I prevent this?
And how can I know the ip address?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053665/sql-injection-pattern-in-store-search

Comment: Check this http://magento.com/security-patch to be sure that your store is up to date. If it is i think you are safe.

Comment: I am using 1.6 and it is far away from safe, I guess.

Comment: Hi, Niloct. I think that link helps a lot